# kendo combo box enable API is not working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I am working on web app using kendo.I need to disable/enable kendo combobox using kendo API but it's not working.

here's my code:

HTML :

```
<input tabindex="5" id="art" kendo-combo-box ng-model="a.b" k-options='airTypeOptions' class="isRequired displayMode" />
```

JQUERY :

```
$("#art").getKendoComboBox().enable(false);
```

Comment: You are using kendo angular directive here, why still using jquery?

Comment: can u gve me a sample code?

Comment: The reason you can't use that because, it's not yet rendered

Comment: @machun ah nice guess and that's make sense..

Answer (score 0):

You can get kendo widget reference without jquery, change your html code like this

```
<input kendo-combo-box="art" tabindex="5" ng-model="a.b" k-options='airTypeOptions' class="isRequired displayMode" />
```

and this is a sample script to disable it by angular way

```
<script>
  angular.module("sample", [ "kendo.directives" ])
      .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
          $scope.disableComboBox = function() {
             // art already defined as kendo combobox
             $scope.art.enable(false);
          };
      })
</script>
```

[**Demo**](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/IxEvA)

Comment: still it is failed in IE11

Comment: Just run my demo on IE11 and it works perfectly.. Maybe your implementation has defect..

Comment: I know your code is perfect...It's not working if I use inline code like above is used for rendering kendo combobox otherwise it is fine.